# Using htaccess to create pretty links - in my non-empty .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

So right now I'm just trying to convert something like

```
https://gregorj.org/post?id=26
```

to

```
https://gregorj.org/post/26
```

Everything I've found (also on stackoverflow) is telling me to put this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)?$ /post?id=$1 [L]
```

But it's not working in my case. I'm assuming this might just be because I have a bunch of other stuff in my .htaccess, that I put there to hide .php and .html extensions back when I started the site (which is also why I wrote /post?id=$1 and not /post.php?id=$1 in .htaccess - but I've tried both just in case :).

Here's my .htaccess as it stands today:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# Prevent POST requests from getting redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Any ideas as to what I can do to get the prettier links?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my own question.

If I start out preventing POST requests from getting redirected, then maybe ^post isn't a great way to start a redirect rule...

I changed it to ^article and no problems

Comment: Whatever the actual problem was, it surely did not have anything to do with the check for method `POST`, and the `post/` part in the URL. Those are two completely different things getting checked here.

Comment: I didn't think so either, but the fact remains that ^article is working, and I can't get ^post to work. No biggie though, I'm not emotionally attached to "post"